# How can i extract last shortest string using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, shortest

how can i extract bold range string in below

> string :
>
> 1. hello world blah -d blah vlaah **-n blah vlahh**
> 2. hello world blah -n blah vlahh **-d blah vlaah**
> 3. hello world blah **-d blaaah**

I tried.  `-[dn] .*$` but it found longest match string like below

> 1. hello world blah **-d blah vlaah -n blah vlahh**

I want to extract shortest match string . thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid matching another `-d/-n` in the match:

```
-[dn] (?!.*?-[dn]).*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY7qW1/6)

Answer (score 2):

Could throw a [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) `.*` before to eat up:

```
^.*(-[dn] .*)$
```

And grab matches of the first [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xP4iJ5/1)